# Differentiate between admin and user php

Tags: php, mysql

Im creating a website where users can login to buy books and collect them from store. I have a login screen where both normal users as well as staff use to login. However im trying to find a way to differentiate between normal users and staff.

I have a table called "users" where one of the columns is called "account_type" which can hold a value of U for normal user and A for admin.

this is the code i currently have:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Starting Session
include_once('config.php');

$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['user']) || empty($_POST['pass'])) {
$error = "Please complete both fields";
}
else
{
// Define $username and $password
$user=$_POST['user'];
$_SESSION['login_user']=$user;
$pass=md5($_POST['pass']);
// To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
$user = stripslashes($user);
$pass = stripslashes($pass);
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $user);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $pass);
// SQL query to fetch information of registered users and finds user match.
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users where Username='$user' AND Password='$pass'");
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
header("location: home.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
}elseif ($rows["account_type"] == "A"){
header ("location: adminHome.php");
}else {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
mysqli_close($mysqli); // Closing mysqlinection
}
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<title>Login</title>

</head>
<body>

<div id = "logReg">
<span href="#" class="button" id="toggle-login">Log in</span> 
</div>

<div id="login">
  <div id="triangle"></div>
  <h1>Log in</h1>
  <form action = "" id = "logregform" method = "POST">
    <p id = "err"> <?php if(isset($error)) {echo $error;} ?> </p>
    <input id = "logtxt" type="text" placeholder="Username" name = "user" required/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name = "pass" required/>
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" name = "submit" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <p id ="bklg">Dont have an account? <a href="register.php">Sign up</a></p> 
  </form>
</div>
<script>

$('#toggle-login').click(function(){
  $('#login').slideToggle('fast'); 
});
</script>
</html>
```

Line 24-30 is where ive put the check but it doesnt seem to work.
I dont get any errors it just skips to the validation part when i try the admins login details and says "username or password is invalid" It does login as the normal user however.

Any ideas?

Comment: make sure config.php  includes  error_reporting(E_ALL); and preferrably  exception_error_handler

Comment: Hi, I dont get any errors even with error_reporting(E_ALL); in the config file.

Comment: Why do you want to implement the 56390472th user management solution? Why not use an existing one?

Comment: @arkascha Sorry what do you mean? im confused

Comment: A general warning: you should _never_ store passwords inside your database, be it in plain text or encrypted. You set your users data at risk for no reason at all. What you should store instead is a hash generated by a good and slated hash algorithm. For authentication you then compare two hashes. This makes it impossible for attackers to steal your users passwords from your database. Note that this is a general pattern, ready-to-use solutions for this exist.

Comment: What I mean by an existing user management solution? Well there are many many sites that already implemented what you are trying to do here. Most of them use open source solutions you can use too. This would save you a lot of time and certainly lead to a more secure solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
header("location: home.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
}elseif ($rows["account_type"] == "A"){
...
}
```

Take a closer look at this.  You are setting `$rows` with mysqli_num_rows, it will not be an array and should only be an integer.  You need to use a fetch function to get the column data.  The fetch would be run using the MySQLi statement variable (in your case the return value of mysqli_query or `$query`.  Read more about fetch here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

P.S.  Your code a little messy.  You use stripslashes then real escape, why not use prepared statements?  They are safer and more efficient because they let the DBMS (MySQL) handle the variables.  Read more about prepared statements here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Ah im fairly new to php. How would i do that exactly?